# Passing a DataTypeEnum

Tags: c#, types, parameter-passing, com-interop

I was getting the following error trying to call a function in a C# project I am creating:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Operation is not allowed in this context.
at ADOX.ColumnClass.set_Type(DataTypeEnum pVal)
```

Update: I am now getting:
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040E3D): Type is invalid.

It's strange though cause if I don't pass any string to a function which should return a DataTypeEnum it works.

I'm calling a function and passing a string "widget(in)" to return the DataTypeEnum field type

```
static public createTable()
{

    ADOX.Catalog cat = new ADOX.Catalog();
    ADOX.Table table = new ADOX.Table();
    table.Name = "Table1";
    ADOX.ColumnClass columnHold=new ADOX.ColumnClass();
    columnHold.Name="FieldX;
    columnHold.Type=setFieldType("widget(in05)"); //this works if nothing passed to function
    columnHold.DefinedSize=setFieldSize("widget(in05)"); //This call works
    cat.Tables.Append(table);
   //more code not listed
}
```

to call the following function which gets the field type from a separate data file and field

```
static public ADOX.DataTypeEnum setFieldType(string fieldName)
{
    //fieldname is from another data file.. skipping the code just to show point
    ADOX.DataTypeEnum fieldType= ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar; 
    return fieldType;
}
```

I used to use something called macro substitution to do this but C# doesn't allow that because of bad habits.

Any idea how to pass the type to the calling function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [`ADOX.Field.Column` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676164(v=vs.85).aspx) is read-only after the column has been added to a table:

> This property is read/write until the Column object is appended to a collection or to another object, after which it is read-only.

The easiest solution is to specify the column type as part of the [Append method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676596(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
table.Columns.Append("field1", setFieldType("widget"));
```

Comment: Thanks I'm getting warmer. I can do it that way or pre-populate it before I add it to the table. Still having a problem if I try to get a return value from a custom function. If the custom function I call doesn't take an input value the custom function returns that DataTypeEnum fine.